# Asp.net Web services (asmx) with varying types of authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-services, authentication, asmx

I need to be able to have some web methods (in asmx) require windows authentication to be used, and others to require no authentication at all. Is this possible? If not, what would you recommend I do, best practices etc?

I am fairly new to web development, sorry if this is trivial.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Every time I run into these mixed authentication scenarios, I find that running separate sites is far easier than trying to mix in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

Create and host two different webservices and separate your methods based on their authentication need. So you can enable windows authentication in one.